# Why all norms define the same relative interior?(Convex Optimization, Stephan Boyd)

Tags: normed-spaces, affine-geometry

When I was reading 'Convex Optimization', Stephan Boyd, I was stopped by Example 2.2.
Before Example 2.2 is started, following definition is coming.

- If the affine dimension of a set $C\subseteq\mathbf{R}^n$ is less than $n$, then the set lies in the affine set $\mathbf{aff}\;C\neq$. We define the $\;relative\;interior$ of the set $C$, as its interior relative to $\mathbf{aff}\;C:$
  $$\text{relint}\;C=\{x\in C\,|\,B(x,r)\cap \text{aff}\;C \subseteq C\;\text{for some}\; r>0\},$$
  where $B(x,r)=\{y\,|\,\|y-x\|\le r\}$, the ball of radius $r$ and center $x$ in the norm $\|\bullet\|$. (Here $\|\bullet\|$ is any norm; all norms define the same relative interior.)
- $\mathbf{Example\;2.2}$ Consider a square in the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane in $\mathbf{R}^3$, defined as
  $$C=\{x\in\mathbf{R}^3\,|\,-1\le x_1\le 1,\, -1\le x_2\le 1,\,  x_3=0\}$$
  Its affine hull is the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane, $i.e.,\;\text{aff}\;C=\{x\in\mathbf{R}^3\;|\;x_3=0\}$. The interior of $C$ is empty, but the relative interior is

$$\text{relint}\;C=\{x\in\mathbf{R}^3\,|\,-1\lt x_1\lt 1,\, -1\lt x_2\lt 1,\,  x_3=0\}$$

I wondering why all norms define the same relative interior. And how we know relint $C$ in $\mathbf{Example\;2.2}$ which is not determined any ball's information(center $x$ and radius $r$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a finite dimensional space, [all norms are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional).

In particular, in Example 2.2 you can use any norm you want to.