# Prove that Trace is a bounded operator, and find its norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, operator-theory

I'm trying to prove that the trace of a matrix $\tau:\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ is a bounded operator, i.e. there is $K>0$ s.t. $|\tau(M)|\leq K\|M\|,$ where $$\|M\|=\sup_{|x|_2= 1}|Mx|_2,$$
where $|\cdot |_2$ denote the euclidian norm of $\mathbb R^n$. Find $$\|\!|\tau\|\!|:=\sup_{\|M\|=1}|\tau(M)|.$$

I'm very confused with all these norms.

---

**Attempts**

1. For the fact that $\tau$ is continuous, it's quite easy since $$|\tau(M)|\leq |M_{11}|+...+|M_{nn}|\leq n^2 \mathcal N_1(M),$$
   where $$\mathcal N_1(M)=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}|M_{ij}|.$$
   I know that $\mathcal N_1$ is a norm on $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$, and since all norms on $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ are equivalent, there is $P>0$ s.t. $\mathcal N_1(M)\leq P\|M\|$. Therefore, setting $K=n^2P$, we get $$|\tau(M)|\leq K\|M\|,$$
   as wished.
2. I have no idea on how computing $|\!\|\tau\|\!|$. I suspect that $|\!\|\tau\|\!|=n^2$, but I have no idea on how to compute it. Any idea ?

Comment: You should mention which norm $\|M\|$ you are using on the matrices. Is it their operator norm considered as maps $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: **Hint :** if $(e_1, ..., e_n)$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $$\tau(M)=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle Me_i,e_i \rangle$$ Now use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @FShrike: As written in my OP, $\|M\|=\sup_{|x|_2=1}|Mx|_2$ where $|\cdot |_2$ denote the euclidian norm on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe:  Applying C-S yields $$|\tau(M)|\leq n\sum_{i=1}^n |Me_i|_2=n(|M_{1i}|+...+|M_{ni}|)\leq n^2 \sup_{k=1,...,n}|M_{ki}|\leq n^2\|M\|.$$ Now, which matrix $M$ could I take s.t. $\|M\|=1$ and $\tau(M)=n^2$ ? I thought $M_{ij}=n\delta _{ij}$ for all $i,j$, but I don't see how to prove $\|M\|=1$, any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every linear operator $T:X \to Y$ on a finite-dimensional normed space is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983050/every-linear-operator-tx-to-y-on-a-finite-dimensional-normed-space-is-bounde)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think C-S yields

$$
|\tau(M)| \le \sum_{i=1}^n|\langle Me_i,e_i\rangle| \le \sum_{i=1}^n |Me_i|_2 |e_i|_2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n\|M\| = n \|M\|.
$$

For $M=I_n$ we have $\tau(M)=n$ and $\|M\| =1$. Hence $||| \tau |||=n$.

Comment: Please search for duplicates before answering! (=:

Comment: @SummerChild In fact I did. Searched under "trace norm" and found the corresponding answer with respect to the Frobenius norm, but not exactly the version above.  I agree that its maybe a dublicate, but I don't search for hours.

Comment: The search took me less than a minute, I just entered: ` "finite dimensional" AND "bounded" AND "operator" `.

Comment: @SummerChild Yes, the link you found shows that $\tau$ is continuous, but say's nothing on the quantity of $|||\tau|||$. In the original question $|||\tau|||=n^2$ was presumed, which is wrong. This was the reason for my answer.