# Norm and modulus, a little help.

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

a little help with Analysis 2.
I know what the definition of a norm is, and I know that in a multidimensional space R^2 I can define infinite "equivalent" functions that respect the properties of Norm.
So I will have infinite equivalent norms from a topological point of view, and I will only change the "distance" that these represent.

Now, in an attempt to ask me why this is so, I have attempted to draw a parallel with R, where the "norm" is the modulus or absolute value.
I saw in a textbook that |x|= max{x,-x} and the parallel with the infinite norm came naturally to me ||v||∞ :=max{|x_i|} but I believe (and correct me if I am wrong) that they are not the same thing.
The modulus is a special case of a norm in R considering the vector space R over the field R.
But I can't figure out when I can consider R a vector space, and how to make a parallel between these two elements.

In R I have the absolute value of x which is a positive value, in R^n I have the sum of absolute values of the components with ||v||_1 or other positive values according to the norm I use.
How do I relate these two elements?

How do I understand why on R^n I have an infinite number of functions that demonstrate norm property and on R only absolute value?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can change the norm on the one-dimensional space $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The absolute value map $x\mapsto |x|$ is not the only norm on $\Bbb R(\Bbb R)$. A scaled absolute value map would also be a norm, ie, $\|x\|:=a|x|$ for some $a\ge 0$ is also a norm on $\Bbb R(\Bbb R)$. For $a=1$, it is the usual absolute value (Euclidean) norm.  But it is true that all norms on $\Bbb R$ are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalence). More generally, [on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, all norms are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57686/215900).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Need $a>0$ or you lose positive semidefinite