# Prove that there exist positive constants a and b such that $a||x||_{1}\le||x||\le b||x||_{1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

also we have to find which is the greatest constant a and the smallest constant b that satisfies the inequality

$a||x||_{1}\le||x||\le b||x||_{1}$

so far I have only proven that you exist $b=1>0$ such that $||x||\le b||x||_{1}$

Observations: For $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$

$||x||=\displaystyle(\sum_{i=1}^p(x_i^2))^\frac{1}{2}$

$||x||_{1} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^p|x_i|$

any suggestions to continue with the test are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Take the minimum over the unit sphere. (Of $\vert\vert$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding of the theorem that all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional)

Comment: By Cauchy-Scwartz $\sum^p_{j=1}|x_j| = \sum^p_{j=1}|x_j|\cdot 1\leq \Big(\sum^p_{j=1}|x_j|^2\Big)^{1/2}\sqrt{p}$. By the trianggle inequality $\|x\|=\|\sum^p_{j=1}x_j\mathbf{e}_j\|\leq\sum^p_{j=1}|x_j|\|\mathbf{e}_j\|=\sum^p_{j=1}|x_j|$. Here $\mathbf{e}_j$ is the vector with $0$ components except at the $j$-th component, which has value $1$.

Comment: @oliver diaz Thank you very much, to determine which is the smallest and largest constant, I thought to define a set and then prove that each one corresponds to the highest and lowest of the set. Is the idea good?

Comment: That $1$ is the best constant for $\|x\|\leq\|x\|_1$ is trivial, since $x=\mathbf{e}_j$ gives you equality. That $\sqrt{p}$ is the best constant for $\|x\|_1\leq\|x\|$ take $x=\sum^p_{j=1}\mathbf{e}_j$. In this case, $\|x\|_1=p$ and $\|x\|_p=\sqrt{p}$. This give you equality in $\|x\|_1\leq\sqrt{p}\|x\|$.

Comment: @oliver diaz I understand. Thank you very much friend for your help.