# Prove that infinity and $l_2$ norms are equivalent for vector spaces of sequences

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm self teaching Metric Spaces and came across this question:

Let X denote the vector space of sequences $x = (x_n)$ with finite sum of squares.
Explain why $||x|| := sup|x_n|$ is a well-defined norm on X. Is the metric induced by
this norm equivalent to the metric induced by the $l_2$-norm?

I've shown that the norm is well defined. From my understanding, these two norms are equivalent. My definition of equivalent metrics is that they are equivalent if the identity map is a homeomorphism. Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: For infinite sequence space these two norms are **not** equivalent. You can easily show this by the fact that $X$ is not complete w.r.t. the sup-norm but complete w.r.t. the $l^2$-norm.

Comment: @Zerox Can I ask why?

Comment: $x_n=(1,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\cdots,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}},0,0,\cdots) \in X$ is a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. the sup-norm but it doesn't converge in the $l^2$-norm.

Comment: @Zerox thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Take $(x_{n})$ with $x_{n}=1$. Then $\|x\|_{l^{2}}=\infty$ but $\|x\|_{l^{\infty}}=1$.

Comment: Amazing, thank you

Comment: @ Zerox This is a proof that the norms are not generally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

For a **finite** dimensional vector space, such as $\mathbb R^n$, all norms are equivalent. See [Understanding of the theorem that all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional) for a proof.

For an **infinite** dimensional vector space, such as $L^p$, the norms are not equivalent. Counter examples were given in the other answers.