# In the multivariate case of Taylors theorem, what norm is used in little o-notation of error term.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Online I have found the definition:

**Taylor's theorem** $\quad$ Multivariate case

$$
\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{a}) + \nabla f(\mathbf{a})^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})^T \nabla^2 f(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) + R_2(\mathbf{x})
\end{align*}
$$

where $R_2(\mathbf{x}) = o(||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}||^2)$ as $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}|| \to 0$.

What is the norm $\|\cdot\|$ used here, when defining the remainder error. Is it the euclidean norm?

Comment: Sure you can use the Euclidean norm, but it doesn’t matter (atleast in finite dimensions) since all norms are equivalent.

Comment: Ok thank you, but what do you mean by all norms are equivalent?

Comment: I guess like what is referred to in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional)

Comment: Your guess is right. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Relation_with_equivalence_of_norms

Comment: Two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$, $\|\cdot\|_2$ are said to be equivalent if they give rise to the same topology; this is easily shown to be equivalent to the existence of two constants $a,b>0$ such that $a\|\cdot\|_1\leq \|\cdot\|_2\leq b\|\cdot\|_1$. In finite-dimensions, this is always the case; for example on $\Bbb{R}^n$, you can easily verify this for the three common norms: the $\ell^1$ norm (i.e the sum norm), the $\ell^2$ norm (the Euclidean norm) and $\ell^{\infty}$ norm (i.e the max/sup norm), but the point is that this is true for all pairs of norms.