Comparability Riemannian Metric in chart
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.
I know the following result: For each $x \in M$ there exists a chart $V$ and a constant $C \geq 1$ such that for all $y \in V$ and $\eta \in T_y \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
 \frac{1}{C}|\eta|_{g_{\mathbb{R}^n}} \leq |\eta|_g \leq  C|\eta|_{g_{\mathbb{R}^n}}.
$$
Now, my professor says, that it is not hard to prove, that for an arbitrary constant $C > 1$ one can find a chart s.t. the above inequality is satisfied. I cant figure out, why it's the case.

Can you think of any possible ways to show this? Or some facts you know that you think might be useful in answering this?

If a vector space is finite dimensional, all norms are equivalent: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional

I got a solution, I will post an answer to my question when I have time.

Let $U \ni p$ be a chart with local coordinates $x^1 , \dots, x^n$. Because of symmetry and positive definiteness of $g^x(p)$ find a non- singular matrix $A$ such that $A^T g^x(p)A = I_n$. Now define a new coordinate system $y_1, \dots, y_n$ by
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix} = A \cdot \begin{bmatrix}y_1\\\vdots\\y_n\end{bmatrix}$$.
Thus, the change of coordinates at $p$ from $x$ to $y$ at $p$ is given by $A$. So,
$$g^y(p) = A^Tg^x(p)A = I_n$$
By continuity and shrinking $U$, and using $y_1, \dots, y_n$ as a coordinate system, we get the result.
