# What is the meaning of the Ky Fan k-norm to be the bridge between sum and max norm

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

In *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson ([page 320](https://books.google.com/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC&pg=PA320) in 2nd Edition), the definition of the k-norm is as follow:
$$\large \|x\|_{[k]} = |x_1| + \cdots\cdots + |x_k|,\text{ where }  |x_1|\geq\cdots\geq|x_k|$$

And a property is as follow:
$$\large \|\cdot\|_\infty = \|\cdot\|_{[1]}\leq\|\cdot\|_{[2]}\leq\cdots\leq\|\cdot\|_{[n]} = \|\cdot\|_1$$

Although I can verify this property , I am very confused.

$\|\cdot\|_\infty $ = max{ abs of the all elements} and $\|\cdot\|_1$ = {sum of all the elements}

How could they be equivalent? (Though they are equivalent through the proof)  I think there is a gap. Any help is appreciable. Thanks!

P.S. You can also explain in matrix language.

Comment: Related to equivalence of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25157/how-to-prove-c-1-x-infty-leq-x-leq-c-2-x-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MartinSleziak In fact , I do not care about the proof. What is the intuition behind the proof( theorem)? I know they are correct

Comment: Well, if you are only interested in the two norms ($\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ it seems more-or-less obvious. The sum of $N$ positive elements is at most $N$-times the maximal of them. And you combine this with triangle inequality. The important thing is that there is only *finitely many* summands.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Assume that all the elements are nonnegative. the sum of all the elements is **absolutely** larger than the maximum. How could they be equivalent?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. $\ell_1$ norm is *defined* as sum of absolute values. (BTW could you perhaps give a more precise reference than just the title of the book?) If needed, we can [continue in this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/8/9), so that we do not leave too many off-topic comments on your question.